# Hystrix class per command?

Tags: java, hystrix

My app has a configurable (at runtime) set of external endpoints to call:

```
/foo
/bar
```

and are used to make http calls using apache HttpClient.

I would like to wrap HttpClient using Hystrix here but I want to separate circut breakers for each endpoint, so that if one fail, it wouldn't affect other.

I could do that by having 2 classes:

```
FooCommand extends HystrixCommand<...> {
}

BarCommand extends HystrixCommand<...> {
}
```

but that's a hardcoded solution and prevents me to dynamically configure this at runtime.

How can I construct a single hystrix command class to achieve this?

Ideally something like this:

```
class MyHystrixHttpClient extends HystrixCommand<Data> {
    public MyHystrixHttpClient(String endpoint) {
        // here somehow tell hystrix to use "endpoint" string getHash() as a grouping key
    }
}
```

So then I could use it like this:

```
new MyHystrixHttpClient("/foo").execute(); // (1)
new MyHystrixHttpClient("/bar").execute(); // (2)
```

and if (1) fails, (2) would still be executed and treated separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the command key in the constructor.  Something like this.

```
public class HttpCommand extends HystrixCommand<HttpResponse> {

  private final HttpClient httpClient;
  private final HttpRequestBase request;

  public HttpCommand(String commandKey, HttpClient httpClient, HttpRequestBase request) {
    super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("HttpGroup"))
        .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey(commandKey)));
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.request = request;
  }

  @Override
  protected HttpResponse run() throws Exception {
    return httpClient.execute(request);
  }

}
```

Comment: Ah you might be right. https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#command-thread-pool gives an example for solving a similar problem. I'll retest that and get back to you